# How to close an open workbook using rubyXL gem

Tags: ruby, excel, rubyxl

I have used below code to read and write from worksheet.But when the worksheet is already in open and if I try to run the code its failing because of permission error.I want to make sure when I hit the run the opened excel file should close.

```
require 'rubyXL'

# reading from excel


workbook=RubyXL::Parser.parse("#{Dir.pwd}/test.xlsx")

# here I want to make sure the excel get closed 

#workbook.close -> this code not working

worksheet= workbook['Sheet1']

header_row=worksheet.sheet_data[1]

header_data=Array.new

header_row.size.times do |i|

  header_data<<header_row[i].value
end

#writing to excel

worksheet.add_cell(0,2,'Pass')
worksheet.add_cell(0,3,'Fail')
workbook.write("#{Dir.pwd}/test.xlsx")
```

Comment: Do you have it open in another program (excel, openoffice or another copy of your script)? If so, then close the file in that program.

Comment: Also, what exactly is the error?

Comment: Error message: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen.

Comment: I want to make the code to close the excel file, if I miss to close the file.

Comment: Well, it seems that you don't have permissions to read the file. Adjust/check filesystem permissions on that file.

Comment: The solution I need is to close the file(here test.xlsx) through the ruby code which was open state already.The code should close the excel file.Thank You.

Comment: You can't close something that you didn't open. If another program has the file open, it's that program's responsibility to close it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I think you didn't get me..I need to close the excel workbook using Ruby code.. something like this workbook.close..consider that the workbook is opened by Ruby code itself.